# Not able to setup react native environment on Apple mac pro2

Tags: react-native

I am new to Mac laptop. My configuration is Apple M2 Pro, macOS ventura version 13.6.

I was trying to setup react native environment on my mac m2 pro. But below type of error keep facing and also Install Cocoapods is the problem.

Error 1: Unknown ruby interpreter version (do not know how to handle): >=2.6.10.

Error 2: Traceback (most recent call last):
2: from /Users/kaviyarasanthavamani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>' 1: from /Users/kaviyarasanthavamani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:296:in` activate_bin_path'
/Users/kaviyarasanthavamani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:277:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)

I was tried to setup react environment on mac m2 pro.